# Prolog, Beginner , Arithmetic

Tags: prolog, grammar

I came with an arithmetic rule to evaluate a simple star by 9.

```
evaluate(A):-eval(A,B).
eval(A,B):- B is 9*A.
```

and I have:

```
?- eval(3,A).
A = 27.

?- evaluate(3).
true.
```

but I want result and not true!. I prefer to see the result like below is it possible?

```
 ?- evaluate(3).
 3*9=27.
```

Comment: You seem to think that prolog's predicates return values. They don't. They are either simply true or false. You use unbound variables to return results.

Comment: I'm supposing when you loaded this program you received a warning about `B` being a "singleton variable" in the `evaluate` clause. This is because it only occurs once. You are instantiating a value to it through `eval` but then not using it. @ChristopherHarris answered showing how you can write the answer within the `evaluate` clauses after you obtain it. That will also eliminate the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to see the output, you can print variables after they are unified - i.e.

```
evaluate(A):- eval(A,B),write(A),write('*9='),write(B),write('.'),nl.
eval(A,B):- B is 9*A.
```

output

```
1 ?- evaluate(3).
3*9=27.
true.
```